# Fast procedure to know which transformations are linear

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, linear-transformations

I have the following transformations:

[image]

How can I tell if the transformation is linear?

Is there a fast way of knowing (by looking at equations)? or do I need to check through the theorems:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Checking the theorems **is** the fast way.

Comment: could you provide me with an example? thanks!

Comment: What is transformed into what? I don't understand. What are the linear spaces, what the functions?

Comment: @JackGal I recommend you first try to solve the problem. I mean, it's very basic. First, try proving linearity for the transformation in $A$. How far did you get? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to use the theorems is this:

Let's take a look at D:
$$\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2} \mapsto \pmatrix{0 \\ 9 x_2}$$

Let's check if it's a linear mapping! This is probably easiest if we just pick some numbers and try it out. Say we transform two vectors and we check for the first condition:

$$\pmatrix{2 \\ 3}+\pmatrix{4 \\ 1} \mapsto \pmatrix{0 \\ 36}=\pmatrix{0 \\ 27}+\pmatrix{0 \\ 9} \;\; \checkmark$$

What about the other condition? Let's again just pick some numbers:

$$4\pmatrix{1 \\ 2} \mapsto \pmatrix{0 \\ 72}=4\pmatrix{0 \\ 9} \;\; \checkmark$$

So D was linear!

Once you do this a couple of times, it will become much faster and you'll be able to quickly spot what a linear and a non-linear transformation looks like.

For instance, one that obviously fails is B, since it gives the square of one of the variables; if you double in the input, you quadruple the output, so that is not linear!

Comment: @JackGal Does it make sense now, or should I elaborate?

Comment: It does thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The right sides must all be (or simplify to) the form $(constant) \times (variable)$, or a sum of those.  Of course the constant could be $1$ or $-1$, in which case you'll just see $(variable)$ or $-(variable)$.
If you see a constant not multiplying a variable, or two variables multiplied together, or a variable to a power other than $1$, then it is not linear.

Comment: Just to make things clearer for the beginner, the constant can be zero.